# angular2 RC.1 : router.navigate() not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I recently upgraded my app from ***Angular 2.0.0-beta.12*** to ***Angular 2.0.0-rc.1***. I am using `router-deprecated` module for routing. After default login route is loaded, `router.navigate(['Newgateway'])` doesn't seem to work correctly.

**RootComponent**

```
import { Component, provide } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { LoginComponent } from './loginComponent';
import {NewGatewayComponent} from './newGatewayComponent';

@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    selector: 'root-comp',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/newgateway',name: 'Newgateway',component: NewGatewayComponent},    
    { component: LoginComponent, name: 'Login', path: '/login', useAsDefault: true},
    { path: '/', redirectTo: ['/Login']}
])
export class RootComponent{ 

  constructor(private _router: Router) {

  }

}
```

**LoginFormComponent**

```
import { Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-form',
    templateUrl: './loginForm.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class LoginFormComponent { 
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
    }   

    // if login is sucessfull, navigate back to specified URL
    redirect(result: any, loginComp: LoginFormComponent) {
       this._router.navigate(['Newgateway']);
    }
}
```

**NewGatewayComponent**

```
import {Component, provide} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'pi-new-gateway-panel',
    template: `
        <h1>Gateway</h1>
    `,
})
export class NewGatewayComponent {
   constructor() {
     console.log('loaded')
   } 
}
```

The problem here is that `router.navigate()` call below in `loginComponent` changes the browser URL to `localhost:4001/newgateway` however component is not loaded. Only after browser page is refreshed, `newgatewayComponent` constructor is invoked.

`this._router.navigate(['Newgateway']);`

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I suggest you create a plnkr to show the problem. And then review the new router features to see if you can upgrade...

Comment: You may like to consider this question once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192628/history-forward-backward-button-doesnt-work-with-angular-2-router/37432091

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok figured out the problem.. missed following dependencies in my package.json

```
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

Comment: why to use these dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you nees to add `/` but the question doesn't provide enough information to be sure

```
this._router.navigate(['/Newgateway']);
```

Comment: tried with /Newgateway.. didn't help.. the code was working with beta 12 though..there is no error on the console either. Please let me know if need any clarification.. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to reason about routing without a running example. Can you create a Plunker to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have included ROUTER_PROVIDERS in your bootstrap function, you should remove it from the providers in your LoginFormComponent.ts.